# Shell script for auto exceute and shut-down of application based on system time

Tags: shell-script

I need to implement auto start-up and shutdown of a application in Suse Linux based on system time. Eg. Start the application at 10am. Shutdown the application at 5pm.
Can this be done using shell scripting?

Comment: Why not `cron` ? you can configure application start/stop script in crontab

Comment: What kind of application? Desktop, service, console? And at user level or root?

Comment: @Rahul I guess crontab should work. I am looking into details. thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can use cron for the same

If you want edit cron job just use `crontab -e` command. It will open preferred (`export EDITOR=vim`) editor with already defined cronjobs. then make an entry as below :

```
# crontab fields
# <minute> <hour> <day of month> <month> <day of week> <command> 
# Start the Application at 10am 
00 10 * * * /path/to/startapp_script  >/dev/null 2>&1

# Stop the Application at 5pm
00 17 * * * /path/to/stopapp_script   >/dev/null 2>&1
```

to know more about cron refer [this](http://en.opensuse.org/SDB%3aCron#crontab_fields) page.

If your application don't have start/stop init script then you can create your own custom init script , Refer following link for the same.

**[Creating Custom init Scripts](http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/feature/15380.html)**

Answer (score 1):

You could use 2 cron jobs, one to start the application at 10am and another to stop it at 5pm.

```
00 10 * * * /path/to/start-script.sh
00 17 * * * /path/to/stop-script.sh
```

If you want them to run only Mon-Fri, it would look like this:

```
00 10 * * Mon-Fri /path/to/start-script.sh
00 17 * * Mon-Fri /path/to/stop-script.sh
```